# Is there something in VIM that behaves like ^E + j?

Tags: vim, scroll

Is there a key-combination that behaves as though I'd press `ctrl-E` followed by a `j`, that is the text scrolls up a line but the cursor keeps where it is, relativ to the screen.

I am aware that I could achieve what I want with a `:map` but before I do I thought I'd rather want to know if there is already some "built-in" functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `CTRL-D` with a count of 1 (not that that saves you anything, really).

The `CTRL-D` command does the same as `CTRL-E`, but also moves the cursor down the same number of lines

Comment: I alreayd suspected that there was nonthing shorter. Your answer probably comes closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `z` command

> z.                      Redraw, line [count] at center of window (default
>                           cursor line).  Put cursor at first non-blank in the
>                           line.
>
> zz                      Like "z.", but leave the cursor in the same column.
>                           Careful: If caps-lock is on, this commands becomes
>                           "ZZ": write buffer and exit!  {not in Vi}

These mappings makes it possible to scroll up and down one line with focus on center line (hard to describe so that it sound correct, try it instead)

```
"scroll with line in center
map <C-Up> <ESC>0kzz
map <C-Down> <ESC>0jzz
```

Comment: Yipe, the redraw is super slow!